# Docker run cron jobs in parallel

Tags: docker, parallel-processing, cron, docker-swarm

### Using simple server

I was using a simple node (centos or ubuntu) to run my web application and also configured some cron jobs there to run schedule tasks. In that moment everything worked.

---

### Using Docker Swarm Cluster

I migrated my application to Docker Swarm cluster. Now the crons are running in multiple containers at same time and that is critical for me. I know Docker is working on new feature called **jobs** but I need a solution for now. I will like to know if there is any way to just run one kind of cron job process.

---

### Blocker

The crons are running tasks like:

- create report about process.
- send notification to another services.
- updating data in the application.

The crons need to be run on the server because were configured to use interfaces and endpoint using php command.

---

### My Problem

I created multiple instance of the same docker service to provide availability. All the instances are running in a cluster of 3 nodes and each of them are running its cron jobs at same time in parallel and I will like to run just one job per docker service.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be a solution to create periodically a docker service with restart condition none and replicas 1 or create a cron container with replicas 1 and restart condition any, it would be the scheduler and attach a volume with the required cron scripts.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options.

1. Use a locking mechanism locking over NFS, or a database (MySQL, Redis, etc). You execute each job like this: `/usr/local/bin/locker /path/to/script args`. It may good to provide the locker options to wait for the lock or fail immediately if the lock is not available (blocking, non-blocking). Therefore, if the job is long-running, only the first one will acquire the lock, and others will fail. You may want to reuse [some existing software](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/lock.html) simplifying the hard job of creating reliable locks.
2. Use a leader selection. When running in a swarm, there must be a mechanism to query the list of containers. List only cron containers, and sort them alphabetically. If the current container's id is the first one, then allow executing. `first=$(get-containers cron | sort | head -n 1); if [[ "$current-id" == "$first" ]]; then ... fi`
3. Run the cron outside of the cluster but use it to trigger jobs within the cluster over the load balancer. The load balancer would pick exactly one container to execute the job. For example `curl -H 'security-key: xxx' HTTP://the.cluster/my-job`.
4. I'm sure there are swarm-specific tools/methods available. [A link.](https://blog.alexellis.io/containers-on-swarm/)